# Prefixing Drupal Folders

Tags: 7, installation

Is it possible to prefix the root Drupal folders? Is there an option/way to define a prefix for theses folders?

e.g /includes/ becomes /drupal_includes/

I'm implementing a site that will begin as part Drupal implementation, part static. So to keep the site tidy it would be nice if I could "mark" the Drupal system.

It's not essential so if it's not simple then it wouldn't be worthwhile.

Comment: Unless you can implement some file system trickery, be prepared to patch a bunch of core/contrib files as they include files from /includes manually in a bunch of cases. The better solution might be to consider anything under /sites as custom (and I guess /profiles if you have any custom profiles). Everything else except the root .htaccess/robots.txt belong to Drupal. It's not a perfect convention but it should work in most cases. in Drupal 8 things are much better, the whole of Drupal core is under a /core folder so you can keep it separate

Comment: Doesn't it make more sense to prefix the custom static stuff than to try and modify Drupal?

Comment: Thanks @Clive that's helpful, so seems it's probably not wise. Beebee yes, I'll use .htaccess to keep the clean URLs but then rewrite to a /static/ directory. Thanks for your help.